# Pass values from django views to django forms

Tags: django

I am trying to pass a value from views.py to forms.py in django

views.py:

```
def pods(request):
    clusterName = request.GET.get('data') ----> this is the value I want to pass to forms
    return render(request,'pods.html',{"nodeForm":forms.getPodsOnNodes()})
```

forms.py:

```
class getPodsOnNodes(forms.Form):   
    nodeName = forms.ChoiceField(label='Node Name',choices=functions.choiceMaker(functions.nodesList(**this is where I want to use clusterName from views**)))
```

Would you please let me know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Considering to get the data from post request passing it to html

```
form = getPodsOnNodes(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    clusterName = request.POST["data"]
    return render(request, 'pods.html', context={'nodeForm': form, 'variable_name': clusterName})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment
I dont want to pass the value to html file, what I am looking for is to pass the value 'clsuterName' for my form and load the choice field based on that
In fact I want to know how I can pass a value from views to forms

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables to your form from the view by calling the form with kwargs :

```
def pods(request):
    clusterName = request.GET.get('data')
    return render(request,'pods.html',{"nodeForm":forms.getPodsOnNodes(nodeName=clusterName)})
```

And in your form, you need to retrieve the value of your kwarg in your `__init__` method (**before the inherited one** or else you'll get an error because of an undefined kwarg). However you'll then need to define your field inside of the `__init__` method as else your `nodeName` variable won't be defined.

So your form class will become like that:

```
class getPodsOnNodes(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nodeName = kwargs.pop('nodeName')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['nodeName'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Node Name',choices=functions.choiceMaker(functions.nodesList(nodeName)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, unfortunately this did not help
I was trying to pass clusterName but using your suggested method I get KeyError: 'clusterName' error

Comment: Yes sorry, I just realized I made a typo in the view part. I changed that so that should be ok now.